# Correct syntax to run this as a sed script

Tags: sed

The sed below works on the command line and does the following

```
sed -n '/CREATE EXTERNAL/,/^[)]/{/^[()]/d;p}' ddl.txt
```

Print  all lines between lines containing CREATE EXTERNAL and ) except those that start with an ( or ) from the file ddl.txt

As you may note the exception for lines starting ( or ) is handled as an embedded address, lines which match it are deleted when encountered.

All attempts I have made to put this into a file that can be run with sed -f have failed. I would be grateful if someone can show me the right syntax.

Here is some test data

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE foo.bar
(
    mykey INT,
    mydata VARCHAR(20),
    lastfield VARCHAR(20)
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\137'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

which should yield

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE foo.bar
    mykey INT,
    mydata VARCHAR(20),
    lastfield VARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What exactly did you put into the file? And how did you run it? I just put `/CREATE EXTERNAL/,/^[)]/{/^[()]/d;p}` into a file and called it with `sed -n -f script.sed ddl.txt`

Comment: Yeah I forgot to do dos2unix. Thanks.